# combine pandas text rows based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, text

I have this kind of df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"text_column" : ['question: everybody is kongfu fighting', 'panda: of course',  'question: Why is the world so great ?', 'friend: Everybody is smart', 'and everybody is cool', 'enemy: no that is just not true', 'jordan: i want to add one thing: please', 'do not talk about this.', ' 2nd question : are you sure ?', 'yeah sure' ]})

                                text_column
0   question: everybody is kongfu fighting
1   panda: of course
2   question: Why is the world so great ?
3   friend: Everybody is smart
4   and everybody is cool
5   enemy: no that is just not true
6   jordan: i want to add one thing: please
7   do not talk about this.
8    2nd question : are you sure ?
9   messi: yeah sure
10  question: you are sure about this ?
11  donald: youre questions are stupid!
```

I want the following output

```
                 type_column                                     new_text_column
0  question: panda:                                        everybody is kongfu fighting of course

1  question: friend: enemy: jordan: 2nd question : messi:  Why is the world so great ? Everybody is smart and everybody is cool no that is just not true i want to add one thing: please do not talk about this. are you sure ? yeah sure
2  question: donald:                                       youre questions are stupid!
```

Basically each question and answer (topic) have to be in one cell.
I could write a function that works but would use apply, which is in general not an optimal solution.
Does anybody have a good idea how to do it?

Comment: Hint: first step is to look at `df.text_column.str.extract('^(.*: )?(.*)$')` and groupby on that.

Answer (score 1):

Define the following functions:

1. "Specialized" split of the source text field into 2 parts:

   ```
   def mySplit(txt):
       tbl = re.split(': ?', txt, 1)
       if len(tbl) == 1:
           tbl.insert(0, '')
       return pd.Series(tbl, index=['Qn', 'Ans'])
   ```
2. Reformat a group of rows:

   ```
   def reformat(grp):
       t1 = ': '.join(grp.Qn.tolist()) + ':'
       t2 = ' '.join(grp.Ans.tolist())
       return pd.Series([t1, t2], index=['type_column', 'new_text_column'])
   ```

Then, to get the result run:

```
df.text_column.apply(mySplit)\
    .groupby(df2.Qn.str.startswith('question').cumsum())\
    .apply(reformat).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It performs:

- Specialized split of *text_column* into 2 columns (*Qn* and *Ans*).
- Cut into groups starting on each row with *Qn* starting with *question*.
- Apply *reformat* to each group.
- Reset the index (discarding the old index).

Comment: thank you; df2.Qn.str.startswith('question').cumsum() this was the part i was missing

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the example what the criteria is for separating.

I'm guessing it's splitting on the colon, so you could try list comprehension

```
df["type_column"] = [x.split(":")[0] for x in df["text_column"]]
df["new_text_column"] = [x.split(":")[1] for x in df["text_column"]]
```